# How can I turn data1 into data2?

Tags: r, stringr

```
 data1 <- data.frame(year = c(2001,2002,2003,2004),
                    locate = c("鄂托克旗、乌海市四合木等","北京市大兴区", "三门峡、洛阳、焦作等市","西峡、南召等县"))   
   data2 <- data.frame(year = c(2001,2001,2002,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004),
locate = c("鄂托克旗","乌海市四合木","北京市大兴区","三门峡市","洛阳市","焦作市","西峡县","南召县"))
```

I wanna turn data1 into data2. I try to use a function to realize it.but there are some errors.

```
pad_city <- function(x,str_detect(x,"等(市|县|)") = TRUE){
   if(str_detect(x, "等$")){
     x <- str_remove(x,"等$")
   } else  {
     last_chr <- str_sub(x,nchar(x),nchar(x))
     x <- str_split(x, "、")[[1]]
     x <- paste0(x, last_chr)
   }
}
```

How can I solve this problem or have an easier way to realize it?

Comment: Do you need `tidyr::separate_rows(data1, locate, sep = '、')` ?

Answer (score 0):

this solution is a little weird, but works without any packages

basically for each year, you create a subset of your dataframe and then paste together all the entries you have in your "locate" column

```
allyears <- unique(data2$year)
words <- sapply(allyears, function(x) paste0(subset(data2 , year %in% x)$locate, collapse=", "))

data.frame(year=allyears, locate=words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

parse_chinese <- function(x) {
  end <- sub("(.+)等(市|县)?$", "\\2", x)
  x <- sub("等", "", x)
  stringr::str_replace_all(x, "、", paste0(end, "|"))
}
data1 %>% mutate(locate = parse_chinese(locate)) %>% separate_rows(locate, sep = "\\|")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
   year locate      
  <dbl> <chr>       
1  2001 鄂托克旗    
2  2001 乌海市四合木
3  2002 北京市大兴区
4  2003 三门峡市    
5  2003 洛阳市      
6  2003 焦作市      
7  2004 西峡县      
8  2004 南召县
```

Comment: data1 <- data.frame(year = c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005),
                    locate = c("鄂托克旗、乌海市四合木等","北京市大兴区", "三门峡、洛阳、焦作、济源等市",
       "西峡、内乡、南召等县","泾源县、隆德县、原州区"))  How can I tidy this data?

Comment: @user14345711 change this `sub("(.+)等(市|县)?$", "\\2", x)` to this `sub("([^等]+)(等(市|县|区)?)?$", "\\3", x)`

Comment: Instead of thanks in comments, you may please award points to correct answers